# Missing column 'frontend_title' in ''civicrm_uf_field_de_DE" after upgrading to 5.1.2

Tags: missing

I have an empty status page and the errors attached below in the Drupal 7 watchdog after upgrading to 5.1.2. Also, the columns in civicrm_uf_field_de_DE don't match columns in civicrm_uf_field (not sure if they should, though).

> $Fatal Error Details = array(3) { ["message"]=> string(23) "DB Error:
>   no such field" ["code"]=> NULL ["exception"]=>
>   object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#433 (8) {
>   ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=> array(6) {
>   ["error_code"]=> string(13) "no such field" ["sql"]=> string(1055)
>   "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as
>   `group_type`, a.title as `title`, a.frontend_title as
>   `frontend_title`, a.description as `description`, a.help_pre as
>   `help_pre`, a.help_post as `help_post`, a.limit_listings_group_id as
>   `limit_listings_group_id`, a.post_URL as `post_URL`, a.add_to_group_id
>   as `add_to_group_id`, a.add_captcha as `add_captcha`, a.is_map as
>   `is_map`, a.is_edit_link as `is_edit_link`, a.is_uf_link as
>   `is_uf_link`, a.is_update_dupe as `is_update_dupe`, a.cancel_URL as
>   `cancel_URL`, a.is_cms_user as `is_cms_user`, a.notify as `notify`,
>   a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.name as `name`, a.created_id as
>   `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.is_proximity_search
>   as `is_proximity_search`, a.cancel_button_text as
>   `cancel_button_text`, a.submit_button_text as `submit_button_text`
>   FROM civicrm_uf_group_de_DE a WHERE (a.name IN ("new_individual",
>   "new_organization", "new_household")) AND (a.is_active = "1") LIMIT 25
>   OFFSET 0 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in
>   'field list']" ["tip"]=> string(62) "add debug=1 to your API call to
>   have more info about the error" ["is_error"]=> int(1)
>   ["error_message"]=> string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
>   ["debug_information"]=> string(1055) "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active
>   as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`, a.title as `title`,
>   a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`, a.description as `description`,
>   a.help_pre as `help_pre`, a.help_post as `help_post`,
>   a.limit_listings_group_id as `limit_listings_group_id`, a.post_URL as
>   `post_URL`, a.add_to_group_id as `add_to_group_id`, a.add_captcha as
>   `add_captcha`, a.is_map as `is_map`, a.is_edit_link as `is_edit_link`,
>   a.is_uf_link as `is_uf_link`, a.is_update_dupe as `is_update_dupe`,
>   a.cancel_URL as `cancel_URL`, a.is_cms_user as `is_cms_user`, a.notify
>   as `notify`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.name as `name`,
>   a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`,
>   a.is_proximity_search as `is_proximity_search`, a.cancel_button_text
>   as `cancel_button_text`, a.submit_button_text as `submit_button_text`
>   FROM civicrm_uf_group_de_DE a WHERE (a.name IN ("new_individual",
>   "new_organization", "new_household")) AND (a.is_active = "1") LIMIT 25
>   OFFSET 0 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in
>   'field list']" } ["message":protected]=> string(23) "DB Error: no such
>   field" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) ""
>   ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(57)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php"
>   ["line":protected]=> int(45) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(10)
>   { [0]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(70)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(3342) ["function"]=> string(12) "civicrm_api3"
>   ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> &string(8) "uf_group" [1]=> &string(3)
>   "get" [2]=> &array(2) { ["name"]=> array(1) { ["IN"]=> array(3) {
>   [0]=> string(14) "new_individual" [1]=> string(16) "new_organization"
>   [2]=> string(13) "new_household" } } ["is_active"]=> int(1) } } }
>   [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(68)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(689) ["function"]=> string(14) "getCreateLinks"
>   ["class"]=> string(20) "CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup" ["type"]=> string(2)
>   "::" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [2]=> array(4) { ["function"]=>
>   string(20) "outputLocalizationJS" ["class"]=> string(18)
>   "CRM_Core_Resources" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(0) { }
>   } [3]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(275) ["function"]=> string(14) "call_user_func"
>   ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(2) { [0]=> string(18)
>   "CRM_Core_Resources" [1]=> string(20) "outputLocalizationJS" } } }
>   [4]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(84) ["function"]=> string(7) "runItem" ["class"]=>
>   string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> &array(12) { ["id"]=> string(2) "61" ["domain_id"]=>
>   string(1) "1" ["path"]=> string(20) "civicrm/ajax/l10n-js"
>   ["access_callback"]=> string(1) "1" ["access_arguments"]=> array(2) {
>   [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "access CiviCRM" } [1]=> string(3)
>   "and" } ["page_callback"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(18)
>   "CRM_Core_Resources" [1]=> string(20) "outputLocalizationJS" }
>   ["breadcrumb"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(7)
>   "CiviCRM" ["url"]=> string(19) "/en/civicrm?reset=1" } } ["is_ssl"]=>
>   string(1) "0" ["weight"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["page_type"]=> string(1) "0" ["page_arguments"]=> bool(false) } } }
>   [5]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(52) ["function"]=> string(7) "_invoke" ["class"]=>
>   string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> &array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(4)
>   "ajax" [2]=> string(7) "l10n-js" [3]=> string(5) "de_DE" } } } [6]=>
>   array(6) { ["file"]=> string(67)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module"
>   ["line"]=> int(445) ["function"]=> string(6) "invoke" ["class"]=>
>   string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> &array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(4)
>   "ajax" [2]=> string(7) "l10n-js" [3]=> string(5) "de_DE" } } } [7]=>
>   array(2) { ["function"]=> string(14) "civicrm_invoke" ["args"]=>
>   array(3) { [0]=> &string(4) "ajax" [1]=> &string(7) "l10n-js" [2]=>
>   &string(5) "de_DE" } } [8]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(37)
>   "/var/www/example.com/app/includes/menu.inc" ["line"]=> int(527)
>   ["function"]=> string(20) "call_user_func_array" ["args"]=> array(2) {
>   [0]=> &string(14) "civicrm_invoke" [1]=> &array(3) { [0]=> string(4)
>   "ajax" [1]=> string(7) "l10n-js" [2]=> string(5) "de_DE" } } } [9]=>
>   array(4) { ["file"]=> string(29) "/var/www/example.com/app/index.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(21) ["function"]=> string(27)
>   "menu_execute_active_handler" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } }
>   ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL } }

Comment: is this a multi language site?

Comment: @petednz Yes, it is.

Comment: I am seeing something similar in civicrm_uf_group and have started investigating what might be the cause.

Comment: Lines 368 to 377 in ..CRM,Core,I18n,Schema.php readpublic function processLocales($tplFile, $rev) {
    $smarty = CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
    $smarty->assign('domainID', CRM_Core_Config::domainID());

    $this->source($smarty->fetch($tplFile), TRUE);

    if ($this->multilingual) {
      CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($this->locales, $rev);
    }
    return $this->multilingual;
  }
 Shouldn't line 375 read CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($this->locales, $rev, TRUE); as it is called during an upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this seems more like upgrade issue for multi-lingual setup. The views are not created properly for the new field thats being added to civicrm_uf_group. The sql looks fine, But YES the columns for  views should match exactly same as table however the label for multi-lingual column may vary.

To fix this i would suggest you to create column in the view or might have re-run code to rebuild Multi-lingual schema(`CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($locales, NULL, TRUE);`)

HTH

Pradeep

Commands (https://gist.github.com/mlutfy/647e6325a09079e4f08f273af64900d9):

## Drupal 7

drush php-eval 'civicrm_initialize(); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(["en_US","fr_CA"], NULL);'

## Drupal 8

drush php-eval '\Drupal::service('civicrm')->initialize(); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(["en_US","fr_CA"], NULL);'

## Drush

drush cvapi System.rebuildmultilingualschema

Comment: Seems that was it, thanks! Added console commands to your answer.

Comment: This just happened to me too, upgrading from a 4.6.38 site to 5.4.1 on Drupal 7.  Pradeep's suggested drush command fixed it.

Comment: Great!!! Glad to hear that my answer was useful to you.