# System Status Page Blank after Upgrade

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, angular, status

After upgrading from 4.7.31 to 5.2.0 the system status page is blank. I made sure the Directory and Resource url settings match; I cleaned up caches and reset paths; I disabled the Asset Cache; no luck. Anything I'm missing?

EDITED TO ADD:

I have since upgraded, and when I go to the status page I get an error that CiviCRM is unable to retrieve an extension. After I update paths, then it just goes to a blank page. The console says: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/status

Comment: Same problem, but simply a 'new' install of 5.1.2.  System status was working, now stopped working after installing some pretty usual Drupal modules

Comment: if your site is a multi-lingual one then may relate to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/missing-column-frontend-title-in-civicrm-uf-field-de-de-after-upgrading-to?noredirect=1#comment28239_25232

Comment: I had this error when an extension caused a fatal error.   Can you look at the logs?  In my case it was the sparkpost extension.  The latest on github solved my issue

Comment: Site is Wordpress and not multi-lingual. @KevinCristiano - could you provide a link to the latest on github?

Comment: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/ the changes are in the master branch.  And there is not a release.  You will have to update manually.

Comment: Made the Sparkpost updates, status page still blank.

Comment: Check your browser developer console, my guess is it would be missing or giving error on some angular jquery files. Check network tab

Answer (score 3):

Here's one answer that fixed my problem (see my comment above).  The cause was that when I created the Drupal system I just used the domain name without the www.  But Civi was loaded with www.  This is an old problem and I'm a bit ashamed to admit I made this mistake again!  But if your system has this mismatch then system status won't work.  Fix was to change the base url in Drupal.

Comment: Am using Wordpress and the base url matches--still blank system status page.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to cleaning up caches via **Administer menu » System Settings » Cleanup Caches and Update Paths**, it also pays to delete the [templates_c](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) directory.

Comment: I routinely clean up the caches, especially when upgrading. The problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Sparkpost extension did the trick.