# Contribution Tab not visible after upgrade to 5.2.1

Tags: civicontribute, localisation, contact-view, i18n

after upgrading CiviCRM 5.2.1 in contacts I contribution tab disappeared.
[image: Contact tabs]

And "Contribution" is checked in Display preferences.
[image: Display preference]

I discovered that it depends that when I save `admin/setting/preferences/display` there is not saved the value `7` for CiviContribute in table `civicrm_setting`. I have executed this query update:

`` UPDATE `civicrm_setting` SET `value` = 's:27:\"123457910111314\";' WHERE `id` = 1 ``

I do not know what it depends...

I have another strange thing: the field `civicrm_option_value.label` is missing (there are `label_it_IT` and `label_en_US` instead).
[image: civicrm_option_value]

I updated CiviCRM from version 4.7.27 and my database has a lot of views. I notice recent CiviCRM database does not have views instead.

What do you suggest me?
Thanks

Comment: Check the CiviContribute component is enabled at 'Administer > System Settings > Components` ... but if was enabled previously it should not have been disabled by the upgrade.

Comment: Yes, it was enabled previously and now! A strange thing is that the tab disappeared when I gave ok in  `admin/setting/preferences/display` (uncheck and check `Enable popup forms`) because I had this problem in view [Missing column 'frontend_title' in ''civicrm_uf_field_it_IT" after upgrading to 5.1.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/missing-column-frontend-title-in-civicrm-uf-field-de-de-after-upgrading-to) that I have fixed.

Comment: I think i have read other tickets about upgrade issues with multilingual sites - since you mention "label_it_IT and label_en_US" this could be part of the issue. May be worth adding that tag to your question

Answer (score 1):

Switch in English language. In "display preferences" you will find the un-flaged contribution field. Flag it and return in Italian language. You will see that it works. I do not know what the reason is, but it works.

"...a buon rendere!"    ;)