# Problem caused by an incorrect translation in CiviGRANT

Tags: civicontribute, civigrant

there is a problem in CiviGrant (Italian) translation for CiviCRM 5.0 and later versions (also at the code level?) that seems to cause problems to the application.

Infact, both for CiviContribute and CiviGrant component, both in the main and secondary menu, now the translation is: "CONTRIBUTI" and this:

1. generates confusion, especially in tokens application (and it is
   semantically no correct).
2. **but above all, it causes a malfunction of the application and the two modules can not be activated at the same time (!!!)**

In CiviCRM 4.7: “Grants” was more correctly translated in: “Contributi/Prestiti” (on, better, in “Finanziamenti”)

However the best translation for “GRANTs” is:

•   SOVVENZIONI

**These are the problems:**

1. As reported [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/contribution-tab-not-visible-after-upgrade-to-5-2-1/25307#25307) **the tab "contributions" often disappears from the summary tab**, especially when it is necessary to act also for other reasons in "dispaly preferences" (for example: to activate and deactivate pop-ups).

   It is necessary to use the work-arround that I have suggested (switch from Italian to English and put the flag on "contributions" again, then go back to Italian) to make the contributions tab appear.

   **However, in new (Wordpress) CiviCRM 5.5.3 installations** (our other instances are the result of an upgrade) **this work-arround does not work and the "contributions" tab never appears.**

   To solve I had to apply a second work-arround: disable the CiviGrant module and edit in *MySQL civicrm_option_value* the label from "contributions" to "grants".

   In any case, the label disappears but at least I can reactivate it with the first work-arround.
2. **In Advanced Search only the Contributions section (Grants) and not Contributions (real Contributions) appear.**

   It is necessary to disable the Contributions component (Grant) in order to see the (real) Contributions section. :(

How do you think we can solve this problem?

Thx&Bye.

Answer (score 3):

I know the translation of CiviCRM in different languages is done by community members using Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/

Personally I have never really looked at this but I would reckon contacting the translation working group (https://civicrm.org/working-groups/translation) on MatterMost here: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/ and offer to make this change will probably be a good step :-)

Comment: I @ErikH, I post issue on civicrm.chat, then I changed "contributi" to "sovvenzioni" on Transifex for CiviGrant, but I do not know what the next step will be (or I do not know if I've done well or if I have to do anything else: my changes are still "unreviewed").

Comment: Thanks for that, infortunately I do not know either! You should contact someone on the chat to check the next steps....