# after upgrade civicrm dashboard missing 5.23.1 drupal

Tags: drupal, upgrade, civicrm-home

I have just upgraded to 5.23.1 from 5.15.2 (Drupal 7.69)
The upgrade screen was a bit "mumbled" but I assumed it worked ok.
When I went back in to Civicrm I first get a message:

> > Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
> >     DB Error: no such field
> >     Return to home page.<<

When I return to home page and click on my record I can see it in Civicrm but there are no menus and I cannot see anyone else or anything else.

Comment: have you cleared out caches / templates_c

Comment: Did the upgrade proceed to the end? or did it get interrupted part way through?

Comment: otherwise you might want to roll back and retry as sounds like your upgrade wasn't fully successful

Comment: Do you have multi-lingual enabled?

Comment: 1. as part of the process I did clear out caches at the end of the upgrade before I attempted to log in.
2. the upgrade did proceed to the end but the normal finish screen was garbled so i really could not see any error messages
i think roll back is the best answer. i have never done that before and not sure what to do. i do have cpanel backups before i started to upgrade.
3. i do not have multi-lingual enabled

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have multi-lingual enabled? than try to rebuild the views to see if it resolves your problem

[Missing column 'frontend_title' in ''civicrm_uf_field_de_DE" after upgrading to 5.1.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/missing-column-frontend-title-in-civicrm-uf-field-de-de-after-upgrading-to)

2. Do you have DB logging enabled? than disabled and enable back again.
3. Else can you check the CiviCRM log/watchdog to get more details of DB error?

Comment: 1. I do not have multilingual enabled.
2. DB Logging - do you mean "Home » Administration » Reports" in Drupal? It lists many missing pages - all events. Where would the error log be? ConfigAndLog has a file with huge number of errors. (CiviCRM.4414d3fbe240bd223427ab7f.log)

I think my best option is to restore from backup and try again. I have never done that before but have been using the Cpanel bakups of home directory and databases.